# Are Binary and String the only datatypes supported in Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

While using a tool, I got a confusion that if Binary and String are the only datatypes supported in HBase.

The tool explains Hbase Storage type and mentioned it's possible values as Binary and String.

Can anyone let me know if this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In hbase every thing is kept as byte arrays. You can check this link:


**[How to store primitive data types in hbase and retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215492/how-to-store-primitive-data-types-in-hbase-and-retrieve)**